# force:inputField doesn't work inside "div" tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have Lightning Parent component that has three inner Lightning components:

```
<aura:component>
   <c:searchComponent/>
   <c:newRequest/>
   <c:requestsList/>
<aura:component>
```

**c:newRequest** component has several **force:inputField** components to display fields for New Request. Based on search query in **c:searchComponent** I want to show/hide **c:newRequest** or **c:requestList**. To implement that I added new event to call function with addClass/removeClass. Markup:

```
<aura:component>
   <c:searchComponent/>
   <div aura:id="newRequest">
      <c:newRequest/>
   </div>
   <div aura:id="requestsList">
      <c:requestsList/>
   </div>
<aura:component>
```

Toggle logic works great but now I can't see force:inputField components! I tried to remove **div aura:id="newRequest"** and force:inputField components displayed correctly. Is that Lightning issue? What is the best practice to handle similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) instead of force:input. There's a bug in this components.

In another hand, this component doesn't inherit the Lightning Design System styling. Use lightning:input if you want an input field that inherits the Lightning Design System styling.

If you needs to add some layouts to divide with custom classes, use [lightning:layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_layout.htm) & [lightning:layoutItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_layoutItem.htm), that works like bootstrap config.

Answer (score 0):

I found that is [Salesforce Known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gDzQAI).

Workaround is to create apex method to get picklist values from the schema and add them to the lightning:select component using iteration.